# SSRS Expression Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a column sg1 with date as string and may have some extra characters like

```
25/10/18 (M) 
25/06/15 (P) this is planned.
```

My date format is DD/MM/YY.
I have to colour the cells based on cell value.
I have written the background colour expression for the column.
The last condition is not working and throwing error.

```
=IIF(Fields!sg1.Value = "W","Khaki",
IIF(Fields!sg1.Value="g","Gray", 
IIF(Fields!sg1.Value="b","Blue",
IIF((LEN(Fields!sg1.Value)=12 And
Format(LEFT(Fields!sg1.Value,8),"YY-MM-DD")<Today),"Pink", 
"Green"))))
```

I am not able to get what is the issue.

Comment: Could you post what the error message is that is being thrown?

Comment: Shouldn't you be formatting the column as "DD/MM/YY", given that is the format of your date? Also, have you considered, in your query, to split the date and the extra characters into two separate columns? It seems like a pain to deal with having a date and a string after.

Comment: @CrazyCucumber I cannot split the date and extra characters separately as it is client prescribed format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complex then I thought. I tested it myself and this way it should work:

```
=IIF(Fields!sg1.Value = "W","Khaki", 
 IIF(Fields!sg1.Value="g","Gray", 
 IIF(Fields!sg1.Value="b","Blue", 
 IIF((LEN(Fields!sg1.Value)=12 And 
 DateSerial(Mid(Fields!sg1.Value, 7, 2),
            Mid(Fields!sg1.Value, 4, 2), 
            Left(Fields!sg1.Value, 2))  
            <Today),"Pink", "Green"))))
```

Where from `25/10/18` is `Mid(Fields!sg1.Value, 7, 2) = 18 (YY)`, `Mid(Fields!sg1.Value, 4, 2) = 10 (MM)` and `Left(Fields!sg1.Value, 2) = 18 (DD)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your last condition with this idea :

```
And
CDate(LEFT(Fields!sg1.Value,8))<Today(),"Pink", "Green")
```

With your fields, this code should be ok:

```
=IIF(Fields!sg1.Value = "W","Khaki",
IIF(Fields!sg1.Value="g","Gray", 
IIF(Fields!sg1.Value="b","Blue",
IIF(LEN(Fields!sg1.Value)=12 And
CDate(LEFT(Fields!sg1.Value,8))<Today(),"Pink", "Green"))))
```